# Is there anything wrong with using an imported config object in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have these settings passed to my component and they are used in various places around the app. Instead of carrying them with me all over the place I initialise a config object with them and then just import it when I need it.

Is there anything wrong with it?

Isn't this how dependency injection works?

Javascript resolves to the same object if the import is in the same place, right?

**Example**

```
// ./cmsSettings.js
const cmsSettings = {};
cmsSettings.initialise = (props) => {
  cmsSettings.settings = { ...props };
};

export default cmsSettings;

// ./App.jsx
import cmsSettings from './cmsSettings';
...

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    cmsSettings.initialise(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The props contain the object with the properties passed by the site (locales, languages, some ids, etc). I need them in various places for when I am getting language translations, making requests to APIs using specific ids and such.

So I have a config file that I initialise when the component is loaded and then import in a file that I need it. It will return the same object because javascript.

**i.e.**

```
// ./apiService
import cmsSettings from '../cmsSettings';
...

const get = () => {
  const url = `${BaseUrl}?id=${cmsSettings.settings.context.ee}&lang=${cmsSettings.settings.context.locale}`;

  return Request.get(url).then(response => response.body.data);
};

export default {
  get,
};
```

My other concern is that I have this initialise function which also has the benefit that allows me to "mock" the object in my unit tests.

Any opinions, advice, for, against?

Answer (score 0):

I use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in my React applications for this purpose. It enables you to specify a `.env` file with configuration variables.

For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Then you can reference those variables anywhere in your application as follows:

```
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```

This approach is cleaner and permits you to keep private settings, api keys, and server or db information out of version control.

This is also the official way of handling environment variables in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). See here for more information: [adding-development-environment-variables-in-env](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Hope that helps!

Comment: But what about if you don't know the values beforehand. This is a component that will be used in different versions of sites so the settings passed by the sites/cms will be different and have to be saved when the component is loading

Comment: You might consider using [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for state management. Redux context permits global access to state. You can hydrate your application's global state from any source, dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It is more like Global \ Singleton pattern, and there is the same issue with it, in your case the 2 biggest is:

- Hard to test (with dependency injection you can pass custom config what is more handy)
- Hard to maintain \ rewrite (if you change the filename, you need to change the
  imports)

And many others...

Dependency Injection is better, or you can use Dependency container framework.
Of course it is depends on the project size, if it is small this solution can be ok.

Comment: Hmm, these settings are pretty much set in stone. There could be a change in the future I guess but it seems unlikely. It is not impossible though... When you say dependency injection, do you mean passing it like a prop in the components?

Comment: Yes. that is an explicit DI, or you can set up setter method to inject it that is implicit DI. The main issue with global\ singleton, is you component has a dependency, what you can not control, in the run-time: example: in the config you have a yellow background, you can not re use a component with red background,  you need to create a new component with different configuration.